# Забыл унарный оператор отрицания

Tags: c++, stl, предикат

есть задача подсчитать количество не пустых smart указателей в векторе. Написан такой код:

(пусть vect будет с типом int)

```
template <typename T>
bool IsEmpty(std::shared_ptr<T>& ptr)
{
    retrun ptr == nullptr;
}

//...some func
auto fullItemCount = std::count_if(vect.begin(), vect.end(), IsEmpty<int>);
```

Понятно, что он сейчас считает кол-во пустых элементов. Как сделать так, чтобы код выглядел максимально красиво? Помню был унарный предикат??, который отрицал значение, которое передается ему. Не могу его вспомнить.

По идее точно должен быть какой то стандартный предикат вместо функции IsEmpty, но я его тоже не нашел.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/logical_not

Comment: Спасибо! То, что нужно

Comment: `auto fullItemCount = vect.size() - std::count(vect.begin(), vect.end(), nullptr);`

Comment: Интересный вариант) Мне помогло использовать std::not1():
`std::cout_if(vect.begin(), vect.end(), std::not1(IsEmpty<int>));`

Comment: Я ошибся... Почему - то на шаблонную версию компилятор ругается. Предыдущий вариант не сработает, а я проверил на не шаблонной функции. Буду думать дальше

Comment: `std::not1` используется для унарных функциональных объектов. В данном примере необходимо использовать `std::not_fn`: `std::cout_if(vect.begin(), vect.end(), std::not_fn(IsEmpty<int>));`

Answer (score 2):

Так достаточно красиво?

```
cout << count_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [](auto p){ return p; });


cout << v.size() - count(v.begin(),v.end(), nullptr);
```